# How do I change the highlight color for selected texts on isearch?

Tags: faces, isearch

When I search a text on `isearch` due highlighed color it is not readable.

Following line does not have any affect on the main selected word on the `isearch`:

```
(set-face-attribute 'lazy-highlight nil :foreground "black" :background "green")
```

Example:

[image]

**[Q]** How do I change the highlight color for selected text on isearch?

Comment: `M-x customize-group isearch`, `M-x customize-group lazy-highlight`

Comment: I have tried `(set-face-attribute 'lazy-highlight nil :foreground "black" :background "green")` which does not change the selected main word on the search

Comment: Customize face `isearch`: Face for highlighting Isearch matches.

Comment: Use `M-x list-faces-display` to find out which face you're interested in. Then use `M-x customize-face`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See these faces:

- `isearch`

  > Face for highlighting Isearch matches.
- `isearch-fail`

  > Face for highlighting failed part in Isearch echo-area message.
- `lazy-highlight`

  > Face for lazy highlighting of matches other than the current one.